# WinSCP alternative with Incremental Search

Tags: software-rec, winscp

I need some alternative for WinSCP. I know that there is a search, but I need some search field, when typing into it, the list of files updates automatically if some of files name match completely or partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) will do it, at least within the current directory.

[image]